# Redgate's SQL Dependency tracker does not show the dependencies for some databases...Why?

Tags: redgate

Redgate's SQL Dependency tracker does not show the dependencies for some databases...Why?These databases have tables,stored procs etc and I have all rights to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular database> right click on it.> go to properties>Options>
The compatibility level was set to SQL Server 7.0.
Changed the compatibility level to SQL Server 2005(90)

Now i am able to view the dependencies.
This is how i resolved the issue.

Finding out the external references is a total different scenario.
Sometimes some databases may not have any external references at all.

Solution to this has been posted on this blog: http://sqldeveloper9999.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/redgates-sql-dependency-tracker-does-not-show-dependencies-on-a-few-databases/

Answer (score 0):

You have to click the button to resolve external references. If it's not that, it's database-specific and time to get in touch with support.